# Ways to arrange $8$ people in $8$ chairs in a row if person $A$ can't sit next to $B$ or $C$.

Tags: permutations, combinations

> In how many ways can I arrange $8$ persons in a row if person $A$
>   can't sit next to person $B$ and person $C$.

I have made the case that $5$  persons ($A,B,C$ are not included) are already in place and I can have such a configuration in $5!$ ways. Now, $A$ can take place between each person and also before and after the first and last person, thus $A$ can be placed in $\dbinom {6}{1}$ and $B, C$ can take place in $5\cdot4$ ways.

So I have $5!\cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 =1440$ ways to do that.

However I don't know if this result is correct since the solution is not available online (this problem comes from Mu Alpha Theta 1991).

Also what are other ways to look at the problem?

Comment: I am not sure what is intended. Are the forbidden configurations only the ones in which A is berween B and C?  Then it is simplest to counr the forbidden configurations, and subtract from $8!$.

Comment: The forbidden configurations are the ones where $A$ is next to $B$ or $C$ .

Comment: Two answers,two different solutions ?Which one is correct?

Comment: @Mr.Y Check the logic of my answer. It matches with Andre Nicholas'. See if you have any problems with what I have written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea is good, but there is a slip  of execution.

Once "the five" and A have been placed, there are $5$ allowed places for B. Now we have  $7$ objects in place, so $8$ "gaps," of which $6$ are allowed for C, for a total of $(5!)(6)(5)(6)$.  Now the answer should agree with the Inclusion/Exclusion answer.

Comment: I always prefer the slicker ways to solve a problem.Thank you !

Comment: You are welcome. As you can see, you had everything absolutely right, except for a minor detail at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Use the *inclusion/exclusion* principle:

- Include the total number of permutations, which is $8!=40320$
- Exclude the number of permutations containing $AB$ or $BA$, which is $2\cdot7!=10080$
- Exclude the number of permutations containing $AC$ or $CA$, which is $2\cdot7!=10080$
- Include the number of permutations containing $BAC$ or $CAB$, which is $2\cdot6!=1440$

---

Hence the number of legal permutations is:

$$40320-10080-10080+1440=21600$$

Comment: Is there some way to avoid inclusion/exclusion principle ? Not that I hate inclusion/exclusion, but I just want to know if there's some kind of 1-1 correspondence one can make .

Comment: @Mr.Y: Well, you could always count the number of permutations which do not include $\neg{C}AB$ or $BA\neg{C}$ or $\neg{B}AC$ or $CA\neg{B}$ or $BAC$ or $CAB$... But it would yield the same effect (in a larger amount of effort).

Answer (score 1):

Total number of ways in which $8$ people can sit without any restriction = $8!$

Consider the cases where $A$ sits next to $B$ and $C$.

We consider $AB$ as a single unit.
Total number of ways in which $A$ sits next to $B$ = $7! \times 2!$

Next we consider $AC$ as a single unit.
Total number of ways in which $A$ sits next to $C$ = $7! \times 2!$

Now in the above computations we have considered the seating arrangements $BAC$ and $CAB$ twice. So we have to subtract that once.

We consider $BAC$ as a single unit.
Total number of ways in which $A$ sits next to both $B$ and $C$ = $6! \times 2!$

Total number of ways in which $A$ sits next to either $B$ or $C$ or both $= 7! \times 2!+7! \times 2!-6! \times 2!$

Required no. of ways $= 8!- (7! \times 2!+7! \times 2!-6! \times 2!)$

Answer (score 0):

Count the ways when they are together  answer is$8!-1680$. Hope it helps you. But 'and' is confusing so i give another answer total ways are $8!$  now consider A,B,C to be 1 so total people =1+5=6 so total arrangements are $2!.8C6$ so total ways are $8!-(2!.8C6)$=$8!-56$ hope it helps you.

Comment: Note and means A is between B and C so i have given the answer accordingly.

Comment: If you give proper wording it would be better to answer.

Comment: You're right.Forgive my unclearness.